# Comparison test

Tags: real-analysis

Show that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty  a_n $ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ are series with $b_n \ge 0$ such that $\limsup_{n\to\infty} {|a_n|\over b_n }\lt \infty $ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n \lt \infty $, then the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges.

I am wondering how do i link given the convergent lim sup and convergent series to the series $a_n$.

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't $b_n$ have to converge? Otherwise $a_n=b_n=1$ is an obvious counterexample.

Comment: Yes it does converge and I forgot to put that on my question.

Answer (score 0):

we are to assume that $\sum b$ converges. the lim sup condition shows $\exists K,N \gt 0. \forall n \gt N, \frac {|a_n|}{b_n} \lt K$

so we have $\forall m,n \gt N$:
$$
\sum_{j=m}^n |a_j| \lt K\sum_{j=m}^n b_j
$$
from which (via Cauchy sequences) the absolute convergence of $\sum a_n$ follows

Answer (score 0):

Let $\limsup\frac{|a_n|}{b_n}=L$.  Then there is an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{|a_n|}{b_n}<L+1$ for $n\ge N$, so

$\;\;\;|a_n|\le(L+1)b_n$ for $n\ge N$.

Since $\displaystyle\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}b_n$ converges, $\;\;\displaystyle(L+1)\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}b_n$ converges and therefore

$\;\;\;\displaystyle\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}|a_n|$ converges by the Comparison Test.